# Fontawesome classes are purged when using @nuxtjs/tailwindcss

Tags: nuxt.js, font-awesome, tailwind-css

I would love to use Fontawesome 6 with Nuxt and Tailwind. I followed the instructions provided at https://fontawesome.com/v6.0/docs/web/use-with/vue/use-with, but in production the Fontawesome classes still are purged.

I created a repo to reproduce the error.
https://github.com/rw-simon/test-nuxt-tailwind-fontawesome.git

Also tried:

- Whitelist the classes in tailwind.config.js
- Whitelist specific class names rather than regex

Where did I go wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide ;)

Cheers
Simon